# Implementing a bootstrap pool in Netty 4.x

Tags: java, netty

I'm trying to implement a async redis client using netty 4.x. After reading the netty source code and doc, it seems like it's more efficient to use the same NioEventLoop[s] which I use as childEventLoop in ServerBootstrap. The question is it seems like I need to attach such a `RedisClientPool` to each `NioChildEventLoop`, otherwise I can not share those cached connections, but the EventLoop is not a `AttributeMap`.
I tried to extend the `NioEventLoop` and overwrite the newChild to return a custom `NioChildEventLoop`(just copied the codes, because it is declared as final) with a`AttributeMap` field so I can share some objects through it.

```
public class NioChildEventLoopWithAttributeMap extends SingleThreadEventLoop {

    private AttributeMap map = new DefaultAttributeMap();

    public <T> Attribute<T> attr(AttributeKey<T> key) {
        return map.attr(key);
    }

    //.... omit the copied codes
}
```

and

```
public class CustomNioEventLoop extends NioEventLoop {
    public EventExecutor newChild() {
        return new NioChildEventLoopWithAttributeMap();
    }
}
```

But in `AbstractChannel` it checks the EventLoop

```
protected boolean isCompatible(EventLoop loop) {
    return loop instanceof NioChildEventLoop;
}
```

I have no idea what to do now, any suggestions? Sorry for my terrible english.

Comment: Yes, I can also use the custom `NioServerSocketChannel` and `NioSocketChannel`, but it seems too complex to resolve such a straightforward problem.

Comment: why do you need to write a redis client? using keep alive connection and a blocking connection pool has the same performance with a non-blocking client under pressure

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record there is a redis-codec for netty4 and netty3 at github:

https://github.com/spullara/redis-protocol